# Find matching rows in 2 dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to get the index of a 2 dimensional Numpy array that matches a row.  For example, my array is this:

```
vals = np.array([[0, 0],
                 [1, 0],
                 [2, 0],
                 [0, 1],
                 [1, 1],
                 [2, 1],
                 [0, 2],
                 [1, 2],
                 [2, 2],
                 [0, 3],
                 [1, 3],
                 [2, 3],
                 [0, 0],
                 [1, 0],
                 [2, 0],
                 [0, 1],
                 [1, 1],
                 [2, 1],
                 [0, 2],
                 [1, 2],
                 [2, 2],
                 [0, 3],
                 [1, 3],
                 [2, 3]])
```

I would like to get the index that matches the row [0, 1] which is index 3 and 15.  When I do something like `numpy.where(vals == [0 ,1])` I get...

```
(array([ 0,  3,  3,  4,  5,  6,  9, 12, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]))
```

I want index array([3, 15]).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You need the [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function to get the indexes:

```
>>> np.where((vals == (0, 1)).all(axis=1))
(array([ 3, 15]),)
```

Or, as the documentation states:

> If only condition is given, return `condition.nonzero()`

You could directly call [`.nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) on the array returned by `.all`:

```
>>> (vals == (0, 1)).all(axis=1).nonzero()
(array([ 3, 15]),)
```

To dissassemble that:

```
>>> vals == (0, 1)
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       ...
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

and calling the `.all` method on that array (with `axis=1`) gives you `True` where both are True:

```
>>> (vals == (0, 1)).all(axis=1)
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

and to get which indexes are `True`:

```
>>> np.where((vals == (0, 1)).all(axis=1))
(array([ 3, 15]),)
```

or

```
>>> (vals == (0, 1)).all(axis=1).nonzero()
(array([ 3, 15]),)
```

---

I find my solution a bit more readable, but as unutbu points out, the following may be faster, and returns the same value as `(vals == (0, 1)).all(axis=1)`:

```
>>> (vals[:, 0] == 0) & (vals[:, 1] == 1)
```

Comment: I tend to favor `np.nonzero` over the `np.where` alias, to avoid confusion with the completely different `np.where(bool, if_true, if_false)` function

Answer (score 17):

```
In [5]: np.where((vals[:,0] == 0) & (vals[:,1]==1))[0]
Out[5]: array([ 3, 15])
```

---

I'm not sure why, but this is significantly faster than
`np.where((vals == (0, 1)).all(axis=1))`:

```
In [34]: vals2 = np.tile(vals, (1000,1))

In [35]: %timeit np.where((vals2 == (0, 1)).all(axis=1))[0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 808 µs per loop

In [36]: %timeit np.where((vals2[:,0] == 0) & (vals2[:,1]==1))[0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 152 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package that I created, you can simply write:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
print(np.flatnonzero(npi.contains([[0, 1]], vals)))
```

Comment: Nice that you made this. You ought to make your affiliation explicit to comply with site rules. I notice that you did in another answer that came up in my research recently.

Comment: can you show some benchmarks otherwise it wont convince me maybe others of using it.