# How to index sparse tensors in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, matrix-indexing

Is there a way to index a cell/section of a sparse tensor like in case of a dense tensor?

```
# dens_tensor.shape = [10, 10, 10]
dense_cell = dense_tensor[0,0,1]
```

If not, does someone know a workaround to index a sparse tensor?

Comment: I would try `tf.sparse_to_dense` and then to use regular indexing and hope that TF would optimize that.

Comment: I run into a memory problem when I dense my tensor.

Answer (score 1):

A SparseTensor has a field called `indices` which would allow you to get a 2D Tensor of dimensions (N, ndims) where N = number of non-zero entries in the sparse matrix, and ndims = dimensionality of the sparse matrix.

Given this 2D tensor, you can certainly search for your required index within the tensor. AFAIK, tensorflow does not have such a search, but you could do a `session.run()` on the 2D tensor, and then search for your index (0, 0, 1) within this 2D numpy array (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823710/5249801).

If you find your required index (0, 0, 1) at say, index `x` in your numpy array `tf.Session().run(sparse_matrix.indices)`, then the value you're looking for is also at index `x` in the dense 2D tensor `sparse_matrix.values`