# numpy: Efficient lookup of multidimensional result for multidimensional key

Tags: numpy, lookup, numpy-ndarray

To motivate the 'efficient' in the title: I am working with volumetric image data which can be up to 512x512x1000 pixels. So slow loops etc. are not really an option, particularly if the images need to be viewed in a GUI. Imagine sitting just 10s in front of a viewer waiting for images to load...

From two 3D input volumes x and y I calculate new 3D output volumes, currently up to three at a time e.g. by solving equation systems for each pixel. Since a lot of x,y combinations are actually repetitive and often even only a coherent meshgrid range is of interest, I am trying to speed up by creating a lookup table for this subregion. Works well, in my test case I need only ca. 3000 calculations instead of 30 million.

Now, to the problem: I am utterly failing at efficiently looking up the solutions of the 30 million x,y combinations from the 3000 solutions lookup table in a numpythonic way!

Let's try with an example:

```
#                    x  y   s1   s2
lookup = np.array([[ 4, 11, 23.,  4. ],
                   [ 4, 12, 25., 13. ],
                   [ 5, 11, 21., 19. ],
                   [ 5, 12, 26., 56. ]])
```

I succeed in getting the index of one x,y pair following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823608/find-matching-rows-in-2-dimensional-numpy-array):

```
ii = np.where((lookup[:,0] == 4) & (lookup[:,1]==12))[0][0] 
s1, s2 = lookup[ii,-2:]
print('At index',ii,':',s1,s2)
>>> At index 1 : 25.0 13.0
```

Q1: But how to vectorize this, i.e get full solutions arrays for the 30 million pixels?

```
s1, s2 = lookup[numpy_magic_with_xy, -2:]
```

Q2: And actually I'd like to set all solutions to zero for all x,y not within the region of interest. Where do I add that condition?

Q3: And what would really be the fastest way to achieve all this?

PS: I'm fine with using 1D image representations by working with x.ravel() etc. and reshaping at the end. Unless you tell me I don't need to and it's just slowing things down. Just doing it to still understand my own code I guess...

Comment: Going through my open questions, I realize I've solved this one here for my particular case a long while back. I see why nobody provided an answer as it would take me too much time I don't have to even turn my solution into a minimal example! However, send me a message if you have a similar question, so I may ultimately still do it...