# numpy equivalent to list.index

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, I can use `list.index` to find the index of an element, e.g. `[1,2,3,4].index(1)` returns `0`, since the element `1` occurs at position `0`. I'd like to do this with multi-dimensional arrays. That is, I'd like to be able to write something like

```
x = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
              [3, 4, 5]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2])
print(x.index(y))
```

The output should be `0`, because again the target element is in the first position.

Using the built-in `list.index` method doesn't work because the `==` operator for numpy arrays returns an array rather than a boolean. And `np.argwhere` doesn't do any broadcasting. I know I could always do

```
idx = 0
while idx < x.shape[0] and (x[idx] != y).any():
  idx += 1
print(idx)
```

but that feels so clumsy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.  Following this example ([Find matching rows in 2 dimensional numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823608/find-matching-rows-in-2-dimensional-numpy-array)):

```
>>> np.where((x == y).all(axis=1))
(array([0]),)
```