# Replacing entire elements in an array

Tags: python, numpy

**Question**
Let's say I have the following array `tile1`

```
[[80 80 80]
  [80 80 80]
  [80 80 80]
  [80 80 80]]
```

I want to replace every `[80 80 80]` element with the array `[1 5 10]`. How can I do that?

**What I have tried**

I tried

```
print(tile1==[80,80,80])
```

And I thought that was pretty useful but then I realized that is the same as

```
print(tile1==80)
```

So when I tried

```
tile1[tile1==[80,80,80]]=[1,5,10]
```

of course it failed. I could only assign values based on basic elements like `tile1[tile1==[80,80,80]]=5`

Comment: If I may be pedantic, those are not elements, those are rows.  The elements of that 2D array are the "80"s.  You might start looking here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823608/find-matching-rows-in-2-dimensional-numpy-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't "entire elements", they are swaths of memory called rows. Numpy arrays are not like lists. Lists store references to nested elements. [Numpy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) are blocks of memory. Shapes and slices represent views with different strides, not multiple layers of indirection.

You can assign to slices using [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). In this case, you need to specify an index that marks all rows containing the elements you want with a boolean and tell the index to fill all columns.

Your replacement array will correctly broadcast to the columns. However, let's look at the index.

```
tile1 == 80
```

This results in an array of the same shape as `tile1` because of broadcasting. `==` does an elementwise comparison. So does this:

```
tile1 == [80, 80, 80]
```

So how do you get a boolean for each row instead of each element? You use [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) along the appropriate axis:

```
np.all(tile1 == 80, axis=1)
```

Or as I like to phrase it using the method version:

```
(tile1 == 80).all(axis=1)
```

And that's about it. The resulting mask has as many elements as `tile1` has rows, so you can use it directly as you did before:

```
tile1[(tile1 == 80).any(1)] = [1, 5, 10]
```

This works because when you leave out trailing indices, they are implicitly set to `:` or `...`. This is a standard feature of [basic indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basics-indexing). You are assigning a 3-element sequence to an `(n, 3)`-shaped index. `n` is determined by the number of `True` elements in the mask, and `3` is the shape of the remaining dimension of `tile1`.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation helps a lot and solved my problem, although I can't say I understand it completely. For some reason numpy's indexing is something difficult to grasp for me. I will read your answer again carefully and go to the link. If you know other resource to understand this, I will be grateful

Comment: @KansaiRobot. I've linked to a couple of pages that will help. Really, the best way is to play with examples as you read the docs. I only understood this stuff reasonably well through practice. Something like https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html might also help.

Answer (score 1):

This might work but will require some testing, I'm just checking if the values are the same across all columns. In this example its `80`

```
arr = array([[80, 80, 80],
       [80, 80, 80],
       [80, 80, 80],
       [80, 80, 80]])
```

`arr[arr.all(1)] = [1, 5, 10]`

```
array([[ 1,  5, 10],
       [ 1,  5, 10],
       [ 1,  5, 10],
       [ 1,  5, 10]])
```

Comment: This is identical to my answer, but without any of the explanatory material

Comment: Oh im sorry, I think we posted our answers at the same time, I didn't see yours