# Locating specific indices and printing corresponding values in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `I` containing two indices `[0,5]` and `[5,8]`. I want to locate these indices in `Ii` and print corresponding values according to `Iv`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

I=[[0,5],[5,8]]

Ii=[np.array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 0,  5],
        [ 2,  5],
        [ 5,  8],
        [ 5, 10],
        [ 8,  9],
        [ 8, 11],
        [ 9, 11],
        [10,  8]]])]

Iv=[np.array([[[0.45202266977297145],
         [0.9977806946852882 ],
         [0.5228951173127738 ],
         [1.083230383898751  ],
         [0.5533588101522955 ],
         [0.5778527989444576 ],
         [1.2288418160926498 ],
         [0.5274353540288571 ],
         [0.5818783538996267 ]]])]

A=[Iv for I in Ii]
print(A)
```

The current output is

```
[[array([[[0.45202266977297145],
        [0.9977806946852882 ],
        [0.5228951173127738 ],
        [1.083230383898751  ],
        [0.5533588101522955 ],
        [0.5778527989444576 ],
        [1.2288418160926498 ],
        [0.5274353540288571 ],
        [0.5818783538996267 ]]])]]
```

The expected output is

```
[0.9977806946852882 ],
[1.083230383898751  ],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find matching rows in 2 dimensional numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823608/find-matching-rows-in-2-dimensional-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
[Iv[0][0][idx][0] for idx, c in enumerate(Ii[0][0]) if list(c) in I]
```

Result:

```
[0.9977806946852882, 1.083230383898751]
```

This code works in your specific case, where Iv contains only 1 array, and also Ii.
You'll need to slightly change it to fit over 1 array in the lists.

If Iv and Ii contain over 1 array:

```
[score[0][idx][0] for (array, score) in list(zip(Ii, Iv)) for idx, coord in enumerate(array[0]) if list(coord) in I]
```

Comment: How do I change it if ```Iv``` and ```Ii``` contains lists of numpy arrays instead of just one array in each?

Comment: Edited the original answer to fit also multiple arrays in the lists.